# ScaleFactor Matlab R2014a Mpc Toolbox

Tags: matlab

I am following the tutorial : http://www.mathworks.com/help/mpc/examples/adaptive-mpc-control-of-nonlinear-chemical-reactor-using-online-model-estimation.html.

During the design of the mpc controller, I found that my computer wouldn't let me do the ScaleFactor step: `mpcobj.MV.ScaleFactor = Uscale(2);`

```
field "ScaleFactor" in structure "ManipulatedVariables(1)" is invalid.>>
```

Is it something special for The version 2014b? I am working on 2014a.Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? I really would like to use the scaling in order to facilitate weight tuning in mpc.

PS: in the structure of mpcobj, I just have Min, Max, MinECR, MaxECR, RateMin, RateMax, RateMinECR, RateMaxECR, Target, Name and Units. No presence of ScaleFactor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, see the [Release Notes](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/mpc/release-notes.html):

[image]